# Dynamic table to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, post, dynamic, html-table

I have dynamic table each time the user will add a new row to fill up the customer information.
After hitting the submit button I need those data in JSON format.

### HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="driver">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center text-info">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center text-info">
                            first name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center text-info">
                            last name
                        </th>

                        <th class="text-center text-info">
                            mobile num
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center text-info">
                            email id
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='firstname'  placeholder='first name' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='lastname' placeholder='last name' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='mobile' placeholder='mobile number' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The JSON data must be in key & value pair. Can anybody suggest how we can do this?

```
[
    {
        "first name": "ashok",
        "last name": "kumar",
        "mobile num": 45,
        "email id": "xyx@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "first name": "arun",
        "last name": "kumar",
        "mobile num": 789,
        "email id": "kum@as.com"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

serializeArray() will Help you once your array of object is formed  to convert it to json you can use JSON.stringify

[jQuery Source](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

> Description: Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and
>   values.

**Updated**

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/68cr70er/3/)

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  var newFormData = [];
  jQuery('#driver tr:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
    var tb = jQuery(this);
    var obj = {};
    tb.find('input').each(function() {
      obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    obj['row'] = i;
    newFormData.push(obj);
  });
  console.log(newFormData);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newFormData);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
pre {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="driver">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center text-info">
          #
        </th>
        <th class="text-center text-info">
          first name
        </th>
        <th class="text-center text-info">
          last name
        </th>

        <th class="text-center text-info">
          mobile num
        </th>
        <th class="text-center text-info">
          email id
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='firstname' placeholder='first name' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='lastname' placeholder='last name' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='mobile' placeholder='mobile number' class="form-control" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email' class="form-control" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='firstname' placeholder='first name' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='lastname' placeholder='last name' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='mobile' placeholder='mobile number' class="form-control" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email' class="form-control" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit">
  <pre id="output"></pre>
</form>
```

Since you want input field as your Key Name and its value as value inside Object so the code below is actually looping through each row and inside it is looping through each column and storing it in obj named Object and then push it into Array newFormData

Comment: Its working great.How your are ignoring the first column(ignoreColumns [0]) because is that what i need.Can you tell me how it is. @CY5

Comment: I am not getting the format.what i am seeing is `[{"name":"name","value":"ashok"},{"name":"lname","value":"kumar"},..]`.i am expecting the data to be like this property-name & value
`[{"row":"0","name": "ashok","lname": "kumar"},
{"row":"1","name": "ashok","lname": "kumar"},..]` @CY5

Comment: Sorry for delay in response.working good & nice explanation.keep on rocking @CY5

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle.The thing is when I am adding new row the sequence are wrong.row number obj values are adding extra one at each time.[see this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/68cr70er/7/) @CY5